# c# get sql query from database

Tags: c#, sql, entity

whether there is a any library of function wchich who can get a full sql query from database? I don't want execute query and get record.

Comment: What do you mean by `full sql query from database`

Comment: int visual studio or sql server managment i can se source code of table by using buton scipt as.. or view code.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about using Entity Framework. Visit: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/

You can then just call your repository e.g.

```
DbContext.Orders.GetAll()
```